# display information from sql db to asp.net webpage

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio

I think what I need is simple but I can't achieve it through asp.net because I am a total beginner.

What I need is to display a field from sql db table to my webpage like this example:

```
Account Information 

    Your Name is: <Retrieve it from db>
    Your Email is: <Retrieve it from db>
```

How should I do that ?

I already have table members.

I need to do this with c# , I am using Visual Studio Web Express 2010

Comment: Your question title says that it is a asp.net webpage, but in your question you state that you are using C#. Could you please clarify which you mean?

Answer (score 4):

First step is add the SQL Client namespace:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

**DB Connection**

Then we create a SqlConnection and specifying the connection string.

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=username;" + 
                                       "password=password;server=serverurl;" + 
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + 
                                       "database=database; " + 
                                       "connection timeout=30");
```

This is the last part of getting connected and is simply executed by the following (remember to make sure your connection has a connection string first):

```
try
{
    myConnection.Open();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

**SqlCommand**

An SqlCommand needs at least two things to operate. A command string, and a connection. There are two ways to specify the connection, both are illustrated below:

```
SqlCommand  myCommand = new SqlCommand("Command String", myConnection);

// - or -

myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
```

The connection string can also be specified both ways using the SqlCommand.CommandText property. Now lets look at our first SqlCommand. To keep it simple it will be a simple INSERT command.

```
SqlCommand myCommand= new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table (Column1, Column2) " +
                                     "Values ('string', 1)", myConnection);

// - or - 

    myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table (Column1, Column2) " + 
                            "Values ('string', 1)";
```

**SqlDataReader**

Not only do you need a data reader but you need a SqlCommand. The following code demonstrates how to set up and execute a simple reader:

```
try
{
    SqlDataReader myReader = null;
    SqlCommand    myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from table", 
                                             myConnection);
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while(myReader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myReader["Column1"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(myReader["Column2"].ToString());
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: yes i need to use sql server , and i successfully do an insert but if i want just to post welcome,( user name from db ) , should i do all of this to post only a name !! ?

Comment: Yes, you would need to follow these steps. Don't worry, it becomes easy after you perform the initial setup and get it connected to your db.

Comment: i understand like 70% but how should i put put column1 value beside " First Name " in my page ?

Comment: Use SqlCommand to query for "First Name", use SqlDataReader to read the value and convert it into a string, and finally concatenate that value to your other string text.

Comment: ok now for the try {} statement , where should i put that ? , i already put my connection like this: public partial class clients_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection badersql = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BADER-VAIO\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=webage;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123"); , now everytime i try to put the "try { } " statement , its gives me an error

Comment: What error are you receiving? The try-catch block is for error handling, so depending on your error it might be indicating to you that you are failing to connect to your db.